# Multithreading and Virtual Memory System

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, operating-system, virtual-memory

I'm trying to model a virtual memory system. What I would like to do is simulate multiple concurrent user processes using multi-threading.

I'm going to take in, through the command line: page size (bytes as ints), the number of pages each process gets in the simulated logical memory, the number of frames in the corresponding simulated physical memory, the number of total processes to simulate, and the actual logical addresses for each process (which will just be arbitrary ints contained in text files).

I guess what is mainly relevant to my question is how to create the n threads on input and fill each thread's array of logical addresses. I'm reading into multithreading but struggling a bit.

I'm trying to work with this thread code:

```
class Proccess implements Runnable {
       Thread t;
       List<Integer> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

       Proccess(String pNum) {
          t = new Thread(this, pNum);
          System.out.println("Child " + t.getName());
          t.start();
       }


       public void run() {
          try {
            //Is this where I want to fill in the addresses list? 
            //I will be reading in a file to do this. Each
            //file is unique for each individual process
            //so I don't have to worry about multiple processes
            //accessing the same file. 
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             System.out.println("Interrupted.");
         }
         System.out.println(".");
       }
}
```

Each process is going to have its own page table as well, and I am open to suggestions on how to effectively add/maintain that.

This isn't for school, so there are no specs I need to follow.